# why schedule() does not lead to deadlock while using the default prepare_arch_switch()

Tags: linux, schedule

In Linux 2.6.11.12, before the `shedule()`  function to select the "next" task to run, it will lock the runqueue

```
spin_lock_irq(&rq->lock);
```

and the, before calling `context_switch()` to perform the context switching, it will call `prepare_arch_switch()`, which is a no-op by default:

```
/*
 * Default context-switch locking:
 */
#ifndef prepare_arch_switch
# define prepare_arch_switch(rq, next)  do { } while (0)
# define finish_arch_switch(rq, next)   spin_unlock_irq(&(rq)->lock)
# define task_running(rq, p)        ((rq)->curr == (p))
#endif
```

that is, it will hold the `rq->lock` until `switch_to()` return, and then, the macro `finish_arch_switch()` actually releases the lock.

Suppose that, there are tasks A, B, and C. And now A calls `schedule()` and switch to B (now, the `rq->lock` is locked). Sooner or later, B calls `schedule()`. At this point, how would B to get `rq->lock` since it is locked by A?

There is also some arch-dependent implememtation, such as:

```
/*
 * On IA-64, we don't want to hold the runqueue's lock during the low-level context-switch,
 * because that could cause a deadlock.  Here is an example by Erich Focht:
 *
 * Example:
 * CPU#0:
 * schedule()
 *    -> spin_lock_irq(&rq->lock)
 *    -> context_switch()
 *       -> wrap_mmu_context()
 *          -> read_lock(&tasklist_lock)
 *
 * CPU#1:
 * sys_wait4() or release_task() or forget_original_parent()
 *    -> write_lock(&tasklist_lock)
 *    -> do_notify_parent()
 *       -> wake_up_parent()
 *          -> try_to_wake_up()
 *             -> spin_lock_irq(&parent_rq->lock)
 *
 * If the parent's rq happens to be on CPU#0, we'll wait for the rq->lock
 * of that CPU which will not be released, because there we wait for the
 * tasklist_lock to become available.
 */
#define prepare_arch_switch(rq, next)       \
do {                                        \
    spin_lock(&(next)->switch_lock);        \
    spin_unlock(&(rq)->lock);               \
} while (0)
#define finish_arch_switch(rq, prev)    spin_unlock_irq(&(prev)->switch_lock)
```

In this case, I'm very sure that this version will do things right since it unlock the `rq->lock` before calling `context_switch()`.

But what happens to the default implementation? How it can do things right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a comment in `context_switch()` of linux 2.6.32.68, that tells the story under the code:

```
/*
 * Since the runqueue lock will be released by the next
 * task (which is an invalid locking op but in the case
 * of the scheduler it's an obvious special-case), so we
 * do an early lockdep release here:
 */
```

yet we don't switch to another task with the `lock` locked, the next task will unlock it, and if the next task is newly created, the function `ret_from_fork()` will also eventually call `finish_task_switch()` to unlock the `rq->lock`